# Artin Proposition 2.4.2.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand Proposition 2.4.2 in Artin's algebra textbook.

> Let $\langle x \rangle$ be the cyclic subgroup of a group $G$ generated by $x$, and let $S$ denote the set of integers $k$ such that $x^k = 1$.
> (a)  The set $S$ is a subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.
> (b) Two powers $x^r = x^s$, with $r \geq s$, are equal if and only if $x^{r-s} = 1$, i.e., if and only if $r - s$ is in $S$.
> (c) Suppose that $S$ is not the trivial subgroup. Then $S = \mathbb{Z}n$ for some positive integer $n$. The powers $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ are the distinct elements of the subgroups $\langle x \rangle$ are the distinct elements of the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$, and the order of $\langle x \rangle$ is $n$.

My only concern is in proving part (c), which I can't fully figure out how to do. I'm going to retrace Artin's proof until it causes me confusion.

We have $S \neq \{0\}$ a subgroup, so by Theorem 2.33 classifying all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, we have $S = \mathbb{Z}n$ for some $n > 0$, where $n$ is the least positive element of $S$. Given $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the division algorithm gives unique $r,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $k = nq + r$, $0 \leq r < n$. so
$$x^k = x^{nq + r} = x^{nq} x^r = x^r$$
since $nq \in S$ (since $S$ is a subgroup) which implies $x^{nq} = 1$. So $x^k \in \{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1}\}$.

The next line of Artin's proof is:

> It follows from (b) that these powers are distinct, because $x^n$ is the smallest positive power equal to $1$.

I do not understand this, nor how he is able to assert that the order of $x$ (and thus $\langle x \rangle$) is $n$. If I knew a priori that $|\langle x \rangle| = n$, Then I could argue that if $x^r = x^s$ for $r,s \in \{0,1, \ldots, n\}$, then $x^{r-s} = 1$ where $r - s < n$, a contradiction, but I don't know this fact, but rather need to somehow deduce it.

UPDATED attempt based on helpful comments:

> Suppose we have $x^a = x^b$ for $a,b \in \{1, x,\ldots, n-1\}$ where we can assume $a \geq b$ without loss of generality. Then $x^{a-b} = 1$ by part (b), where $0 \leq a - b < n$. Since $a - b \in S$ and $n$ is the least positive element of $S$, we have $a - b = 0$, so $a = b$. Therefore, the powers $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ are distinct. Since $n$ is, by definition, the least positive $n$ for which $x^n = 1$, we have $|\langle x \rangle| = |x| = n$.

Comment: You're basically there. Suppose there are $r$ and $s$ in $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ with $x^r = x^s$.  You can assume without loss of generality that $r \geq s$.  Then $x^{r-s} = 1$, as you note, and (as you did not note, but is true by the assumption that $r \geq s$) you have $0 \leq r-s < n$.  If $r-s$ were positive, this would be a contradiction (because $n$ is the smallest positive power of $x$ equal to $1$).  So $r-s=0$.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. $n$ by definition is the smallest positive integer in $S$ (that's theorem 2.33), so it's already *by definition* the order of $\langle x \rangle$. It suffices to establish distinctness of powers, as you've done. Is that correct?

Comment: @leslietownes Seems appropriate to make this an answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: I added an updated attempt. Can someone tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $e$ the $G$ identity and let $n=|\langle x\rangle|=\text{ord}(x)$. (a) becomes clear because $$\ker(\varphi)=\mathcal S:=\{k\in\Bbb Z:x^k=e\}$$ where $\varphi:k\mapsto x^k$ defines the group homomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z^+\to\langle x\rangle$.
$$\therefore\;x^r=x^s\iff x^{r-s}=e\iff x^{nq+t}=e\iff x^t=e\iff t=0\iff n\vert(r-s)$$ $$\therefore\;(b)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\therefore\;\ker(\varphi)=n\Bbb Z$$
where $r-s=nq+t$ and $t$ is the non-negative remainder after $r-s$ is divided by $n$. Finally, we have (c) because $n=|\langle x\rangle|=\text{ord}(x)$ and thus $x^1,x^2,\dots,x^n$ are the distinct $\langle x\rangle$ members.